# Pytorch progress bar disappear on vscode jupyter

Tags: python, pytorch, progress

I have problem when training Pytorch model, the progress bar of is disappeared by no reason today. It still work properly the days before. I'm using jupyter through vs code, connect to the kernel that run on the Ubuntu subsystem. How can I show the progress bar as normal

[image: Here is my screen]

Comment: I have the similar issue with a fresh env. I recognized the very mystic error output: `Widget load failure [object Object]`. Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue and it seems to come from a problem with tqdm for new versions of ipywidget (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8552).
As mentioned in the link, I solved it by downgrading ipywidgets:

```
pip install ipywidgets==7.7.2
```